# Command do not fire with multipart form (JSF 2.2)

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, file-io, jsf-2.2, servlet-3.1

I’ve been trying to use the new h:inputFile from JSF 2.2, but I cannot get it to work. Ever since I have changed the “enctype” attribute of the “h:form” tag, the action is not being invoked anymore.

I have stripped my application from all Filters and web libraries, but it still does not work.

Here are file contents to make it clearer:

The web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
    version="3.1">

    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.VALIDATE_EMPTY_FIELDS</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>facelets.LIBRARIES</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/soupsocial.taglib.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

</web-app>
```

The faces-config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faces-config xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_2.xsd"
    version="2.2">
    <lifecycle>
        <phase-listener>org.dejava.service.soupsocial.DebuggerPL</phase-listener>
    </lifecycle>
</faces-config>
```

The form fragment:

```
<h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <h:inputFile id="file" value="#{newProjectIdeaController.displayImage}" />
    <h:message for="file" />
    <h:commandButton value="Upload" action="#{newProjectIdeaController.createProject()}" />
</h:form>
```

And the managed bean:

```
@ConversationScoped
@SoupSocialCtx
@Named("newProjectIdeaController")
public class NewProjectIdeaController extends AbstractNewProjectController implements Serializable {

    /**
     * The display image for the project.
     */
    private Part displayImage;

    // Getter/setter

    /**
     * @see org.dejava.service.soupsocial.controller.philanthropy.AbstractNewProjectController#createProject()
     */
    public void createProject() throws IOException {
        ...
    }
}
```

I have created a phase listener in order to debug the request, and the request goes directly from RestoreView to the RenderResponse phase.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

P.S.: I am using WildFly 8.0.0.Alpha4.

Comment: Which JSF impl/version? If applicable, did you try the latest one? For instance, Mojarra had serious `xmlns.jcp.org` namespace trouble in 2.2.0/2.2.1 which are fixed as per 2.2.2 (it's currently already at 2.2.3).

Comment: I am using the WildFly default implementation. If I am not wrong, it is the Mojarra 2.2.1. I will try upgrading it, and will let you know if it works.

Comment: @BalusC , no luck. If it helps, the WAR I am deploying is inside of a EAR.

Comment: This appears to be related to this bug: https://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-3018

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating the version solved it. I am using WildFly 8.0.0.Final.